# how to check where an element is in a list

Tags: python, list

i am trying to check where in the list a element is so i can replace it in that position in a separate list

i have tried to do this using .index but this only works when done in reverse

```
variable = input("enter a number")
list1 = ['1','2','3','4']
list2 = ['0','0','0','0']
L = 0
L = list1.index(variable)
list2.pop(L)
list2.insert(L, variable)
print(list1)
print(list2
```

i expected the output to be:

```
['1','2','3','4']
['1','0','3','0']
```

but the output was:

```
['1','2','3','4']
['3','0','0','0']
```

Comment: Strange. When I run your code, I don't get `['3','0','0','0']`. I get `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. If I add the missing parenthesis, I get `NameError: name 'variable' is not defined`. Please double-check that the code here 100% matches the code you're running, and [edit] your post.

Comment: i removed list1.remove(variable) and sorry about the messy code i should have fixed all the names now

Comment: Can you specify the ``variable`` value?

Comment: its a inputed value again sorry

Comment: You ``pop`` and ``insert`` on ``list2``, So how ``list1`` changed?

Comment: So to be clear, you are trying to copy the element at a particular index in list1 into the same index in list2?

Comment: yes i am trying to

Answer (score 0):

> **The `del` statement** There is a way to remove an item from a list given its index instead of its value: the del statement. This differs from the pop() method which returns a value. The del statement can also be used to remove slices from a list or clear the entire list (which we did earlier by assignment of an empty list to the slice) [**reference**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement)

**Code:**

```py
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list2 = ['0', '0', '0', '0']

variable = '1'
idx = list1.index(variable)

del list1[idx]
list2[idx] = variable

print(f"list1: {list1}")
print(f"list2: {list2}")
```

**Output:**

```
list1: ['2', '3', '4']
list2: ['1', '0', '0', '0']
```

Also, you can delete a slice of a `list` with `del`:

```py
>>> list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> del list1[2:3]
>>> list1
['1', '2', '4']
```

---

If you use `insert()` you will get this:

> **list.insert(i, x)** Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so a.insert(0, x) inserts at the front of the list, and a.insert(len(a), x) is equivalent to a.append(x). [**reference**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html)

**Code:**

```py
list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
list2 = ['0', '0', '0', '0']

variable = '1'
idx = list1.index(variable)

del list1[idx]
list2.insert(idx, variable)

print(f"list1: {list1}")
print(f"list2: {list2}")
```

**Output:**

```
list1: ['2', '3', '4']
list2: ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

---

Implement this with `pop()`:

> **list.pop([i])** Remove the item at the given position in the list, and return it. If no index is specified, a.pop() removes and returns the last item in the list. (The square brackets around the i in the method signature denote that the parameter is optional, not that you should type square brackets at that position. You will see this notation frequently in the Python Library Reference.) [**reference**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html)

**Code:**

```py
def do_some_stuff(variable):
    list1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
    list2 = ['0', '0', '0', '0']

    idx = list1.index(variable)
    list2[idx] = list1.pop(idx)

    print(f"list1: {list1}")
    print(f"list2: {list2}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_some_stuff(variable='1')
```

**Output:**

```
list1: ['2', '3', '4']
list2: ['1', '0', '0', '0']
```

Answer (score -1):

The `.index` isn't the problem, the `.pop`/`.insert` is.

Instead of:

```
list2.pop(L)
list2.insert(L, guess)
```

do:

```
list2[L] = guess
```